# What is the best way to monitor individual APs on an Cisco 5508 WLC?

Tags: cisco, monitoring, wlc

I need to generate a notification for APs that have lost connectivity so that we can proactively dispatch a tech to troubleshoot. We have about 150 APs on our controller. Looked into Cacti and PRTG, but they don't seem to be able generate notifications for the subordinate "objects". I have looked into Zabbix, but haven't been able to spend the time to learn it yet. Any suggestions?

Comment: Cisco NCS Prime was designed for exactly this problem.  It raises an alarm when an AP drops off the controller

Comment: @credd144 - A more interesting question is why are your APs dropping off? Perhaps we could assist there :-)

Comment: Cisco Prime does look compelling.

Comment: We use Cisco Prime to monitor/configure hundreds and hundreds of APs across multiple remote sites. Critical software for Cisco centric enterprises but there is also a substantial licensing/price tag that comes with it :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're open to a commercial solution, SolarWinds has a fairly good wireless monitoring portion in its Network Performance Monitor product that includes a pre-built alert for thin AP's going down.

Some information on its wireless monitoring is [here](http://www.solarwinds.com/solutions/wireless-network-monitor.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

As @Mike Pennington suggested, **Cisco Prime** would be the best all-around-solution for monitoring Cisco LWAPs connected to Wireless LAN Controllers as you gain much more than just a simple ping alert mechanism.  **Wireless requires a systemic view** that considers not only individual APs going up and down -- and any good wireless deployment has allowances for that to prevent a single AP being so disruptive to the system -- but includes the ability to see AP coverage and overlap as well as interference.

Since wireless is inherently a dynamic system responding to environmental changes -- bodies moving about, different reflections of signals from static objects moved on occasion, and AP power adjustments from detection of surrounding friendly or rogue APs -- you need a platform that deals with all this (as the WLCs do) and a network management system that shows you this system view with the ability to alert when issues arise.